# ajax change the global javascript variable do not work

Tags: javascript, ajax

I define a variable in the jsp file,then in the including *.js file's ajax function I change the variable,but It's not work.
In the Ajax I had set **async: false**.
My jsp code is:

```
<script type='text/javascript' > 
   window.leave=1;
</script>
 <script src="${ctxPath}/js/registerchange/registerchange.js" type="text/javascript">      </script>
....
<!--then I call the function change() in registerchange.js -->
```

the change() function in registerchange.js is

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 async: false,
 url:projectpath+"/registerChange.do?cmd=update",
 data:{"str":str,"changeBefore":changeBefore,"fk_ChangeProject":fk_ChangeProject,"sbdNum":sbdNum,"ifShow3":ifShow3},
 contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
 success:function(data){
     window.leave = 2;
 } });
```

After call the ajax function,in the jsp file I use window.leave variable,it is still 1.
Any suggestions will be help,thx.

Comment: are you refering the variable after ajax success or ajax call?

Comment: @karthick in the ajax success function the variable it really changes value to 2.

Comment: i just tried in fiddle -->> http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/L9cx17dr/

Comment: @karthick If I put all my js function in the jsp file,it works.But when I sepearte two,it do no work.

Comment: I know what makes result different.It's my problem , I change the value in somewhere after call ajax.